# automate ui - button event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to automate the clicking of my WPF application's button:

Details of the button using UISpy.exe:

```
AutomationElement
  General Accessibility
    AccessKey:  ""
    AcceleratorKey: ""
    IsKeyboardFocusable:    "True"
    LabeledBy:  "(null)"
    HelpText:   ""

  State
    IsEnabled:  "True"
    HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"

  Identification
    ClassName:  "Button"
    ControlType:    "ControlType.Button"
    Culture:    "(null)"
    AutomationId:   "JumptodirectoryButton"
    LocalizedControlType:   "button"
    Name:   "Edit Directories"
    ProcessId:  "5784 (GUI)"
    RuntimeId:  "7 5784 46496694"
    IsPassword: "False"
    IsControlElement:   "True"
    IsContentElement:   "True"

  Visibility
    BoundingRectangle:  "(1683, 885, 104, 23)"
    ClickablePoint: "1735,896.5"
    IsOffscreen:    "False"

ControlPatterns
  Invoke
```

I tried to do this:

```
AutomationElement aeDirectory = null;
aeDirectory = aeMasterBuild.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Edit Directories"));
if (aeDirectory == null)
    throw new Exception("No Edit Directory button");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Edit Directory button present");

Console.WriteLine("Clicking on edit directories button");
InvokePattern ipClickDirectories = (InvokePattern)aeDirectory.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
ipClickDirectories.Invoke();
Thread.Sleep(1500);
```

and I still get the exception "No Edit Directory button".

What am I doing wrong?

I tried using `AutomationID`, `ProcessID` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your ui tree structure looks like, but try changing TreeScope.Children to TreeScope.Descendants and see if that still doesnt work for you.